# Automate Photoshop CS3 Guide Creation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation

Is there any way create multiple guides on the fly in Photoshop in an automated fashion? For example I want to create horizontal guides every 18px all the way down my document(which is 1000px tall). I started by going to View -> New Guide, then typed in 18px, then repeated and typed in 36px, and so forth. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a grid would do for you? You can hide/show it in the view menu and you can set the size of the grid under preferences. As I have the German version, I can't exactly tell you the english menu names.